# OpenLayers 3: Missing Tiles when map is wrapped horizontally

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I am encountering a strange error when my map is being wrapped horizontally. See image below for the problem. I have three layers in the map: the grid, countries, and the colors. As you can see the grid is being generated. Also I am using Geoserver 2.6.1 to generate the tiles. Any insight on the problem would be helpful.

[image]

Code for map creation:

```
this.map = new ol.Map({
    controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
        new ol.control.ScaleLine()
    ]),
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        projection: projection,
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 2
    })
});
```

The layers get added dynamically but here is a general way I create the layers:

```
        var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
            id: i,
            title: layerName,
            layerName: layerName,
            layerIndex: i,
            source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                url: this.geoServerUrl,
                serverType: 'geoserver',
                params: {
                    'LAYERS' : layerName,
                    'TILED': true,
                },
            })
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer. All of the tiles get loaded when you set the "wrapX: true" on each layer source. This becomes problematic with different projections but it solves the issue of loading all of the tiles.